# iOS, How to like a page on facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-like

is there a way to like a page on a button Click. 
I've tried many snippets like this one

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/"];
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/likes", @"6783623567"];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"access_token" : [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken]};

    [httpClient postPath:link parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *op, id result) {

        NSLog(@"result %@", result);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"error %@", error);

    }];
```

but it fails with "Application does not have the capability to make this API call.","type":"OAuthException","code":3".
what I'm doing now is to open the link inside a webview.

Answer (score 0):

Everything [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_iOS_6_Facebook_and_Twitter_Integration_using_SLRequest#Using_SLRequest_and_the_Account_Framework) for the code, and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/publishing/) for the publishing actions on Facebook, such as likes... :)